# Can make the AsyncTask run every X seconds in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask at my Android application that grabs a Array of integers through a socket and after it passes at UI thread.

Here is the code of it

```
public class CardTask extends AsyncTask<ObjectInputStream, Void, int[]> {

private int[] arrayFromServer = new int[16];

public CardTask() {

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected int[] doInBackground(ObjectInputStream...params) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = params[0];
        try {
            arrayFromServer = (int[]) (ois.readObject());
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayFromServer;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...arg1) {

}
}
```

and I pass the array to my UI in this way.

```
 pickCardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myPlayer.addCardToMyPile(touchedCard);

            /** AsyncTask Initiated */
            new CardTask() {

                @Override
                public void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
                    cardsFromServer = result;
                    updateCards(cardsFromServer, pCards);
                }
            }.execute(ois);
 }
    });
```

Code works good but I have a question. As you can see my AsyncTask is under a `Button Listener` and I would prefer if it was running every X seconds without the button pushed. Can be done? I have to do it in another way?

Thanks for your time and replies.

Comment: Have a look at the Handler class - that may be what you want.

Comment: Do it with the Alarm Manager class and the Intent service, you save battery that way and it will work regardless if your app is in forefront or not

Comment: @MarkSmith Handler class? I will check it out. Thanks man.

Comment: schedule by using TimerTask and Timer